# Display Images with Timer doesn't work

Tags: android

Hello I need to display 12 imagen for 5 second when I clicked in the Menu Inflater, in the option "Start".

I create a method for show the Images:

```
private void mostrarImgs() {

    if ( ultT < prtT ) {   
        if (mostrar) { 
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[ultIndice])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[prmIndice])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
        }
    }
    mostrar = !mostrar;   
    }
```

And in the 'Inflater:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.texto1:
 Timer cambioImg = new Timer();
        cambioImg.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mostrarImgs();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 180 * 1000);
        return true;
```

I have the problem that It doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: You are never setting the visibility to `VISIBLE`!

Comment: I did it in the method mostrasImgs ()

Comment: No, your are setting `INVISIBLE` in both lines.

Comment: Change this `if (mostrar) { 
        ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[ultIndice])).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you set on both cases setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE). So Always are INVISIBLE, you need to change one of them

Comment: So I have to put if ( ultT < prtT ) {   
        if (mostrar) { 
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[ultIndice])).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[prmIndice])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
private void mostrarImgs() {

if ( ultT < prtT ) {   
    if (mostrar) { 
        ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[ultIndice])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        ((ImageView)findViewById(imgIds[prmIndice])).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    }
}
mostrar = !mostrar;   
}
```

You have to make one of those `VISIBLE` otherwise, they will always be `INVISIBLE`

Comment: I did it but nothing happen :S